# How to pick a row randomly based on a number of tickets you have

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, random

I have this table called `my_users`

```
my_id | name | raffle_tickets
1     | Bob  | 3
2     | Sam  | 59
3     | Bill | 0
4     | Jane | 10
5     | Mike | 12
```

As you can see `Sam` has `59` tickets so he has the highest chance of winning.
Chance of winning:

- `Sam` = `59/74`
- `Bob` = `3/74`
- `Jane` = `10/74`
- `Bill` = `0/74`
- `Mike` = `12/74`

PS: `74` is the number of total tickets in the table (just so you know I didn't randomly pick `74`)

Based on this, how can I randomly pick a winner, but ensure those who have more raffles tickets have a higher chance of being randomly picked? Then the winner which is picked, has 1 ticket deducted from their total tickets

```
UPDATE my_users
SET raffle_tickets = raffle_tickets - 1
WHERE my_id = --- Then I get stuck here...
```

Server version: 5.7.30

Comment: @Akina Updated my post

Comment: 74? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8+

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT name, SUM(raffle_tickets) OVER (ORDER BY my_id) cum_sum
          FROM my_users ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT SUM(raffle_tickets) * RAND() random_sum  
          FROM my_users )  
SELECT name
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
WHERE cum_sum >= random_sum
ORDER BY cum_sum LIMIT 1;
```

For 5+

```sql
SELECT cte1.name
FROM ( SELECT t2.my_id id, t2.name, SUM(t1.raffle_tickets) cum_sum
       FROM my_users t1
       JOIN my_users t2 ON t1.my_id <= t2.my_id
       WHERE t1.raffle_tickets > 0
       GROUP BY t2.my_id, t2.name ) cte1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT RAND() * SUM(raffle_tickets) random_sum
             FROM my_users ) cte2
WHERE cte1.cum_sum >= cte2.random_sum
ORDER BY cte1.cum_sum LIMIT 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9856f9d4b59485d033a5136987c0c73)

Comment: I don't have 8+. I don't understand what CTE's are

Comment: @Jackie Query for 5+ version added.

Answer (score 0):

You want a weighted pull from a random sample.  For this purpose, variables are probably the most efficient solution:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, (@t := @t + raffle_tickets) as running_tickets
      from my_users u cross join
           (select @t := 0, @r := rand()) params
      where raffle_tickets > 0
     ) u 
where @r >= (running_tickets - raffle_tickets) / @t and
      @r < (running_tickets / @t);
```

What this does is calculate the running sum of tickets and then divide by the number of tickets to get a number between 0 and 1.  For example this might produce:

```
my_id   name    raffle_tickets  running_tickets       running_tickets / @t
1       Bob          3                3               0.03571428571428571
2       Sam         59               62               0.7380952380952381
4       Jane        10               72               0.8571428571428571
5       Mike        12               84               1
```

The ordering of the original rows doesn't matter -- which is why there is no ordering in the subquery.

The ratio is then used with `rand()` to select a particular row.

Note that in the outer query, `@t` is the total number of tickets.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5dbf81ae8b15bd92b53532820a51fe7e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Run fails on Mysql 5.7

Comment: @Jackie . . . It works fine in MySQL 5.7.  db<>fiddle is broken for MySQL 5.7.  I changed it to MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Why does the running tickets keep changing?

Comment: @Jackie . . . That is just a cumulative sum.  The ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? Because sam doesn't show up as often as he should. Its almost like there is no weight to each row. I ran it 5 times and sam came up twice, and everyone else came up the other times

Comment: @jackie . . . I'm pretty sure it is correct.  Sam should appear in slightly more than half the results, and 2 out of 5 is a very reasonable result.  You would need to run it dozens or hundreds of times to get a reasonable distribution.